# SQL query where record does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having trouble coming up with a sql query to identify records where a user is missing providers that should be listed in the userproviders table.

**Providers**

```
ProviderID
ProviderName
```

**User**

```
UserId
UserName
```

**UserProviders**

```
UserID
ProviderID
```

I'm trying to identify users that do not have any `ProviderID` assigned in the `UserProvider` table or do not have a specific provider listed in the `userproviders` table.

```
select * 
from users u 
left join UserProviders up on u.UserId = up.ClientId 
where up.ProviderId is null
```

This gets me records where the user doesn't have any provider assigned, but its possible that the user could have a provider but is missing some other needed provider.

Thanks for any help!

For example 
There are 3 providers in the provider table

```
Providers
1, A
2, B
3, C



User
1,Bill
2,Ted
```

User 1 has 2 records in UserProviders

```
Userproviders
1,1
1,2
2,1
2,3
```

So in this example I want to be able to determine that Bill doesn't have a record in Userproviders for provider 3 and that Ted doesn't have a record for provider 2.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by a "needed provider" or "should be" listed.  Without clarity on that point, I don't know how to answer.

Comment: Perhaps take your query, dump results into temp table and query against that with a `NOT IN` filter in your `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want all missing user/provider combinations, then use a `cross join` to get all combinations of users and providers.  Then remove the ones that exist:

```
select u.userid, p.providerid
from users u cross join
     providers p left join
     userproviders up
     on up.userid = u.userid and up.providerid = p.providerid
where up.userid is null;
```

If you just want users that have no provider at all, use `not exists`;

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from userproviders up
                  where up.userid = u.userid
                 );
```

If you want users who don't have a specific provider, then use `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from userproviders up
                  where up.userid = u.userid and up.providerid = ?
                 );
```

Comment: I do not believe that `CROSS JOIN` is appropriate here.  That could be an *enormous* result set to curry-through .. by hand?!

Comment: Thanks, that got me there. I was able to use the third option and a union to get all the combinations of missing providers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, It appears you can Use "IN" Like so:

```
select * 
from users u 
left join UserProviders up on u.UserId = up.ClientId 
where up.ProviderId NOT IN ( select providerId from UserProviders Where UserId != u.UserId )
```